# MySQL: Normalization and Table Join for a Tags Feature

Tags: php, mysql, tags

My Current Database Structure:

```
     `images`            `tags`             `images_tags`
 ________________    ______________    ________________________
| id | title     |  | id | name    |  | id | image_id | tag_id |
|----|-----------|  |----|---------|  |----|----------|--------|
|  1 | Ivysaur   |  |  1 | fire    |  |  1 |     2    |    1   | Charizard: fire
|  2 | Charizard |  |  2 | flying  |  |  2 |     2    |    2   | Charizard: flying
|  3 | Squirtle  |  |  3 | water   |  |  3 |     1    |    4   |   Ivysaur: grass
|  4 | Pidgey    |  |  4 | grass   |  |  4 |     4    |    2   |    Pidgey: flying
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯    ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯    ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

I want to output tags with their respective values (name).

```
if ($_GET["pokemon"] == "2") {
    // output Charizard's tags: fire, flying
}
```

But I am struggling at coming up with a proper query to do this. INNER JOIN is unfamiliar to me and an explanation on how it works would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pokemon. LOL! xD

To output tags:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM tags AS t 
   INNER JOIN images_tags AS r ON r.tag_id =t.id
   INNER JOIN images AS i ON r.image_id =i.id
WHERE i.id ='2'
```

1. Select from the tags table and alias it as "t"
2. Join the third table (association) with the alias "r" and with r.tag_id =t.id
3. Join the images table with the alias "i" and with r.image_id =i.id
4. Finally sets the filter: i.id ='2' (but will be `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pokemon'])` since you do not want SQL injection)

Now a shortcut:

```
if(isset($_GET['pokemon')) {
    $image_id = (int) $_GET['pokemon'];
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT t.* FROM tags t, tags_images r WHERE r.tag_id =t.id AND r.image_id ='$image_id'");
    while($tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        echo $tag['name'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should stop promoting the `mysql_*` API. It is more then 10 years old and shouldn't be used for writing new code. We have [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) with prepared statements now.

Comment: I actually do not use it since I rely on frameworks. But good point.

Answer (score 1):

Good schema design, your query would look like:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tags AS t
INNER JOIN image_tags AS it ON it.tag_id = t.id
WHERE it.image_id = 2;
```

Inner Join simply means that any row in the tags table, MUST have a corresponding row in the image_tags table.

Answer (score 1):

For your current table structure:

```
SELECT
    tags.name
FROM tags
    LEFT JOIN image_tags ON tags.id = images_tags.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN images ON images_tags.image_id = images.id
WHERE images.id = 2
```

But i would suggest you to make some changes in the structure.

1. get rid of image_tags.id .. it is pointless. You can create a [composite primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) from combination of both tag_id and image_id.
2. stop anonymous `id` column. It is useless habit people pick up from bad tutorials and worse ORM libraries. The ID for `tags` table should have same name in both `tags` and `image_tags` table. It will make your DB structure easier to follow, and have one additional *perk* for the query :

   ```
   SELECT
       tags.name
   FROM tags
       LEFT JOIN image_tags USING(tag_id)
       LEFT JOIN images USING(image_id)
   WHERE images.image_id = 2
   ```

Makes it so much easier to read .. don't you think ..

To understand how `JOIN` statements work, [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) might help. Also, I would recommend reading [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: Surely your kidding about point #1? Have you ever had to delete from a linking table with more than 2 columns? It's a nightmare. And restructuring to #2 schema for a simply query is not a good idea.

Comment: So Doctrine is a worse ORM? -.-'

Comment: @MikePurcell , i fail to see how getting rid of pointless column makes any difference when deleting a unique entry?! And the point of #2 was to create more comprehensible naming convention and the simpler query was just an additional perk.

Comment: @Keyne , as ORM there is nothing wrong with Doctrin 2.x .. hell, its the only one actually implementing DataMapper pattern on PHP side of things. But you should not learn SQL from it.